# How to statically check a graph validity?

Tags: haskell

Consider the code below.

```
newtype NodeAT = NodeAT String deriving (Show,Read,Eq,Ord)
newtype NodeBT = NodeBT String deriving (Show,Read,Eq,Ord)
newtype NodeCT = NodeCT String deriving (Show,Read,Eq,Ord)
newtype NodeDT = NodeDT String deriving (Show,Read,Eq,Ord)

nodeA = NodeAT "nodeA" 
nodeB = NodeBT "nodeB"
nodeC = NodeCT "nodeC"
nodeD = NodeDT "nodeD"


data Graph n m = Graph
 { vertices :: n
  , edges :: m
 }

graph1 = Graph  (nodeA,nodeB,nodeC,nodeD)  ((nodeA,nodeC),(nodeB,nodeC),(nodeA, nodeC))
```

Is there any possibility to use the type system to check that edges pairs are instances of nodes belonging to vertices tuple ? 
This would make by construction

```
graph2 = Graph (nodeA, nodeB) (nodeA, nodeC)
```

illegal and failing at compile time ?

Comment: I think it's doable if you use heterogeneous lists instead of tuples.

Comment: Tho I don't see any point in doing this. Graphs are usually dynamic so the vertices/edges must have the same type and you can get vertices directly from edges so don't need to store them both.

Comment: This is too complex to achieve. I guess in principle one might use some GADTs, singletons, and related techniques to enforce this statically, but it wouldn't be completely automatic. On construction, the user would need to provide a proof for the invariant -- this could be made automatic in some cases (e.g. when only literals are involved), but not all.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it fits your needs, but you can come a long way with a bit of type-level programming.

Some extensions are needed of course:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
```

Here is a closed type family for testing whether a type is a member of a type-level list of types:

```
type family Elem a as :: Bool where
  Elem a '[] = False
  Elem a (a : as) = True
  Elem a (b : as) = Elem a as
```

Now, let's define types of vertices and edges where vertices are drawn from a given list of vertex types:

```
data Vertex :: [*] -> * where
  V :: Elem a as ~ True => a -> Vertex as

type Edge as = (Vertex as, Vertex as)
```

Then, we can define a type of graphs where the vertices are stored in its type and its edges in a data constructor:

```
data Graph :: [*] -> * where
  G :: [Edge as] -> Graph as
```

Here are some vertex types:

```
data NodeA = NodeA
data NodeB = NodeB
data NodeC = NodeC
```

With that, the following graph is well-typed:

```
graph1 :: Graph [NodeA, NodeB]
graph1 = G [(V NodeA, V NodeB)]
```

But the following is not:

```
graph2 :: Graph [NodeA, NodeB]
graph2 = G [(V NodeA, V NodeC)]
```

It fails with:

```
  error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘'False’ with ‘'True’
        arising from a use of ‘V’
    • In the expression: V NodeC
      In the expression: (V NodeA, V NodeC)
      In the first argument of ‘G’, namely ‘[(V NodeA, V NodeC)]’
```